# How to Use an Existing Signing Profile for Lambda Functions in AWS CDK?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, code-signing

We deploy our Lambda functions using the `AWS CDK` and need to sign all Lambda code with a single, existing `signing profile`. While I understand how to create and apply a new `signing profile` within a Lambda's definition, this approach doesn't meet our needs. Instead, we want to utilize an already existing signing profile.

Here's how we currently apply a new signing profile:

```
SigningProfile signingProfile = SigningProfile.Builder.create(this, "SigningProfile-resId")
                .platform(Platform.AWS_LAMBDA_SHA384_ECDSA)
                .build();

CodeSigningConfig codeSigningConfig = CodeSigningConfig.Builder.create(this, "codeSigningConfig-resId")
                .signingProfiles(List.of(signingProfile))
                .build();

return Function.Builder.create(this, functionName)
                .runtime(----)
                .architecture(---)
                .handler(handler)
                .code(----)
                .codeSigningConfig(codeSigningConfig)
                .memorySize(memorySize)
                .role(functionRole)
                .timeout(Duration.seconds(timeoutInSeconds))
                .environment(functionEnvironmentVariables)
                .description(description)
                .build();
```

How can we modify this to use an existing signing profile instead of creating a new one?